# x86 Assembly (AT&T): Is there a built in function for determining the minimum/maximum of two values?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

I am implementing a program in Assembly that requires be to determine the minimum or maximum of two registers and values. Is there a built-in function in Assembly like `imul` or `addl` that allows me to do this, or do I have to implement this from scratch using a combination of `cmpl` and `mov` statements?

Comment: No single instruction AFAIK.  With Pentium Pro or later you can use conditional moves and do `cmpl %eax, %ebx ; cmovll %eax, %ebx` etc.

Comment: If your numbers are in vector registers, there are some vector instructions for max and min, but whether that's worthwhile would depend on your application.

Comment: FYI, the term is "instruction" not "built in function" or "statement".

Comment: Look at optimized compiler output for `std::min` / `max`.  @Nate is correct, you'd normally use cmov for scalar integer, or SSE4.1 `pmaxsd` for integers in XMM registers.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes, I found the answer :D